# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

When i'm trying to run either TestNG Test or testng.xml I am getting this exception.

I am using maven project and bitbucket Git for repostiory. I was able to run the testNG Test, testing.xml  and also mvn test command as normal until today when I sync the maven project to GIT from Eclipse.

I have tried refreshing, cleaning, reinstalling testNG , cloning the project after first commit from GIT. I shall really appreciate if someone can help me on this I have done through if someone had the same issue but suggestions did not help.

I shall really appreciate if someone can help, spend over 4 hrs on this issue and not getting any joy.

**Eclipse Error msg:**
Package: testScripts and 
 browserLaunchTestCase.java

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: testScripts.browserLaunchTestCase
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:539)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:109)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: The same problem in Eclipse, in Idea works without any errors